# What is the topology of the structure group of a fiber bundle?

Tags: manifolds

I dont know how can we topologize the structure group G of a fiber bundle P:E\rightarrow B
by transition functions \psi_i^j (Osbern)

Do you know an easy and fundamental book on fiber and vector bundles?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question would be appropriate for the math.stackexchange website.  Please look at the FAQ.  In a fairly general situation $G$ is the group of homeomorphisms of the fibre with compact-open topology.  Steenrod's "Fiber Bundles" book while a little dated is still a wonderful book.  

Answer (score 1):

There's Steenrod's "The Topology of Fibre Bundles".